# jquery best way to remove all classes and all ids from div, ul, li, span, a

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to remove all classes and all ids from all div, ul, li, span, a  within a div with id="remove"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "best" ? ... shortest, fast working ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative to the other answers using find.

```
$('#remove').find('div, ul, li, span, a').removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class');
```

Comment: `$("#remove").find(..)`  is **exactely the same** as `$(..., "#remove")`. The last option is just a shorter way to write `.find(..)`.

Comment: @RobW, to me it seems a little more readable with the `.find(..)`, but it's just personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are

```
var context = $("div#remove");
$("div, ul, li, span, a", context).removeAttr("class").removeAttr("id");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("div, ul, li, span, a","#remove").removeClass()
```

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a demo for you, you can check it from there.

http://jsfiddle.net/TxcAB/1/

```
$("#remove").click(function(){
   $("div,ul,li,a").each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("id");
                $(this).removeAttr("class");

    })

})
```